# Proof check: limit of a product of two functions $f(x)g(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

If $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = A$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x) = B$, $\forall \epsilon >0$, there is a $\delta$ s.t. $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ then

$|f(x) - A| < \epsilon$ and $|g(x) - a|<\epsilon$,     (1)

prove that $\forall \kappa > 0$ there exists $\gamma$, s.t. $0 < |x - a| < \gamma$ then

$|f(x)g(x) - A\cdot B|< \kappa$

My attempt at a proof:

$(f(x) - A)(g(x) - B) = f(x)g(x) - A\cdot B - B(f(x) - A) - A(g(x) - B)$

$f(x)g(x) - A\cdot B = (f(x) - A)(g(x) - B) + B(f(x) - A) + A(g(x) - B)$

$|f(x)g(x) - A\cdot B| < |f(x) - A||g(x) - B| + |B||f(x) - A| + |A||g(x) - B|$

Now I can use (1)

$|f(x)g(x) - A\cdot B| < \epsilon^2 + |B|\epsilon + |A|\epsilon$

I can now choose $\kappa$, such that $\kappa = \epsilon^2 + |B|\epsilon + |A|\epsilon$ (this equation has always a positive soluton for $\epsilon(\kappa)$)., then for this $\kappa$, $\gamma = \delta$ and

$|f(x)g(x) - A\cdot B| < \kappa$

so $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)g(x) = AB$.

Comment: Be careful in the definition of the neighborhood of $a$ (first few lines). It should be $0<|x-a|<\delta$, and same for $\gamma$.

Comment: Also, in the definition on $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$, you have the quantifiers in the wrong order.  The quantifier $\forall \epsilon$ should precede, $\exists \delta$, i.e. you should write, “$\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta$ so that if $0 < |x -a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) -A| < \epsilon$ and $|g(x) - B| < \epsilon$.